# How to use mocking for test uploading file with jest

Tags: vue.js, axios, jestjs, nuxt.js

I am developing a system with nuxt js and jest that in part of that I want to upload an image.

Here's my html code:

```
<input
    id="photo"
    ref="photo"
    type="file"
    name=""
    class="form-control d-flex"
    @change="uploadPhoto"
>
```

Here's my uploadPhoto function in nuxt js:

```
uploadPhoto () {
    const file = this.$refs.photo.files[0]
    // upload photo
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('photo', file)
    const returnedData = await this.$axios.$post('/api/photo/upload', formData, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    })
}
```

The question is:

How may I mock uploading photo in jest to test my code?

My jest code is  something like this:

```
test('uploading photo test', () => {
wrapper = mount(UploadPhotoComponent, {
  stubs: {
    NuxtLink: true
  },
  mocks: {
    $auth: {
      loggedIn: true,
      $storage: {
        _state: {
          '_token.local': 'api bearer token'
        }
      }
    },
    $axios: {
      $post: jest.fn(() => {
        return Promise.resolve({
          status: 200,
          message: 'photo was uploaded successfully.',
          entire: []
        })
      })
    }
  }
  
  })
})
```

I don't know how to test uploading file in jest using mocks.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: That jest code looks like it would correctly mock the axios call. What's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have realized how to do that. First of all generate an image blob and file:

```js
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

const dummyImgData = fs.readFileSync(
  path.join(__dirname, '../../libs/dummy-img-2.jpeg')
);

const fbParts = [
  new Blob([dummyImgData], {
    type: 'image/jpeg'
  }),
  'Same way as you do with blob',
  new Uint16Array([999999999999999])
];

const fbImg = new File(fbParts, 'sample.png', {
  lastModified: new Date(2020, 1, 1),
  type: 'image/jpeg'
});
```

And after assign it to `$refs` object:

```js
wrapper.vm.$refs = {
  photo: {
    files: [
      fbImg
    ]
  }
}
```